# "Generate method" suggestion doesn't support overloaded methods

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm using C# in Visual Studio Community 2019, version 16.5.1. I use ide suggestions a lot (I'm talking about sugestions indicated by yellow buld in ide), yet there is one lacking feature I'm finding quite annoying. I'm posting example code to visualise my problem:

```
        public void Foo(int value)
        {
            //some code
        }

        public void Foo(string value)
        {
            //some code
        }

        public void Main()
        {
            Foo(GetParam());
        }
```

Method GetParam() doesn't exist yet. When i place text cursor on `Foo(GetParam())` and click yellow bulb, all I can see is suggestion "Generate method GetParam", which will create method `int GetParam()`. I would like to have a choice, whether I want method returning string or int. Is there any option in IDE or workaround for this inconvenience?

Comment: you could always create a local variable first with the type you expect and pass that to `Foo` - ie `int foo = GetParam(); Foo(foo)`

Comment: Resharper will give you the choice of return values, but I if VisualStudio doesn't do it by default, I doubt there's an option to change it. The current behavior is to generate a method for the first matching signature in the class. Interestingly, if you add a generic signature first (`public void Foo<T>(T value)`), VS will generate a method that returns an `object`, whereas resharper only gives the non-generic options if they exist.

Comment: I’m afraid, this is by design. I suggest you could also start VS > Help > Send Feedback > Suggest a Feature… and suggest this feature directly to Visual Studio Product Team.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest at least two choices here.

1) Assign method result in a variable with a specific type, like:

```cs
 int result = GetInt();
 string sRes = GetString();
```

when you will use **Visual Studio** to create a method it will automatically have a return value `int` and `string` for the above examples.

[image]

---

2) Use [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), which is really great tool, enhancing Visual Studio capabilities.

[image]